# Rails: How do I parse translation strings from Loco to separate yaml files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml

We use Loco for our translations and Ruby on Rails as our framework.
We have the following directory structure for our locals in rails

```rb
config:
  locals:
    views:
       api:
         v1:
           users:
             en.yml
       users:
         en.yml
       posts:
         en.yml
```

Our translations in Loco for those views are tagged with "View".

We receive them from the Loco-Export-API and are getting the following string:

```
"en:\n  api:\n    v1:\n      users:\n        show:\n          foo: bar\n  users:\n    show:\n      foo: bar\n  posts:\n    show:\n      foo: bar\n"
```

After parsing it with `YAML.load` we're getting:

```
{"en"=>{"api"=>{"v1"=>{"users"=>{"show"=>{"foo"=>"bar"}}}}, "users"=>{"show"=>{"foo"=>"bar"}}, "posts"=>{"show"=>{"foo"=>"bar"}}}}
```

That's exactly what we are expecting and will work with rails' lazy lookup.

The actual problem happens now: We want this into the separate files from the file structure from above.

But we have no idea how we can achieve this.

The final result should be 3 files containing:
api/v1/users/en.yml:

```yaml
en:
  api:
    v1:
      users:
        show:
           foo: bar
```

users/en.yml

```yaml
en:
  users:
    show:
      foo: bar
```

posts/en.yml

```yaml
en:
  posts:
    show:
      foo: bar
```

Can anyone help us with this?

EDIT:

We found a very ugly solution to find out the root keys:

```
def finding_keys(hash, temp_keys = [], overall_keys = [])
  hash.each_pair do |k, v|
    if v.to_a.flatten[1].is_a?(Hash)
      temp_keys << k
      temp_keys, overall_keys = finding_keys(v, temp_keys, overall_keys) # More keys to follow
    else
      overall_keys << temp_keys
      temp_keys = []
    end
  end

  return temp_keys, overall_keys
end
```

`_, overall_keys = finding_keys(yaml['en'])`

Content of overall_keys: `[["api", "v1", "users"], ["users"], ["posts"]]`

With this we can create the folders.

```
overall_keys.each do |keys|
  FileUtils.mkdir_p(Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', 'views', *keys)) # create folder
end
```

But how can we write the correct translation into the files now?

If we use `yaml['en'].dig(*overall_keys.first).to_yaml` we are only getting:
`"---\nshow:\n  foo: bar\n"`